# Databases columns-width function is not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am trying to archive fixed column width https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width with responsive datatables

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
"columnDefs": [
{ "width": "20%", "targets": 0 }
]
} );
```

but if the column text is grater than specified with like ( "width": "20%") it is auto resizing the column width.
how can i restrict itto  fit within column width and trim excess using ellipsis ?

Comment: set `autoWidth: false` and remember to declare all columns' width in order to not get surprised.

Comment: can you provide us an example, then i can give you a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this css to you datatable  `width: 100% !important;word-wrap: break-word;`it will work for you.

```
<script>

     $('#example').dataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [
        { "width": "20%", "targets": [0] }],
           fixedColumns: true
        } );

</script>

.customDataTableLayout {
    width: 100% !important;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

E.g

```
 <table class="customDataTableLayout" width="100%">
       <thead>
         <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>student name</th>
         <th>student Code</th>
         <th>Status</th>
         </tr>
        </thead>
     </table>
```

Comment: You are declaring `.customDataTableLayout`  but refers to `#companyDataTable` - how should that work? What is the point of having both `width: 100% !important;` in the CSS and `width="100%"` as element attribute?